# Can bushes help keep driveway and patio gravel stable?

Tags: shrubs, landscaping, hedge, hard-landscape, gravel

My front yard has a U-shaped driveway on a significant slope. The arrows in the diagram below indicate the downward direction of the slope. From the bottom right to the top left, the elevation drops about 3'.

According to my design, there will be a level round patio in the middle.  The patio and the driveway will be covered with two distinct species of gravel. On the low side, there will be a quarter-circle retaining wall supporting the patio. On the high side, the patio will flow into the driveway. But in-between, there will be a 2'-wide sloped strip that spans the two elevations.

My question is: if I planted bushes on that strip, can they serve as a separator between the patio and the driveway? Would they keep the patio gravel contained in the patio? Would they help keep the stope on the strip stable? And can they be planted on a slope to begin with?

[image]

Comment: Gravel doesn't work well on slopes, how is it being applied?  Laid three inches deep and compacted heavily or ?????  Tell us about your climate and any snow clearing that goes on..